# ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6) app failed to build on AppHarbor. Any idea why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I've tried to publish a sample MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5) app to AppHarbor. But it always failed to build. Here's the build log from AppHarbor:

```
Build started 12/21/2014 6:09:32 PM.
 1>Project "D:\temp\3s5ri4qs.5at\input\WebApplication1.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
 1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
     Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
 1>Project "D:\temp\3s5ri4qs.5at\input\WebApplication1.sln" (1) is building "D:\temp\3s5ri4qs.5at\input\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.kproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
 2>D:\temp\3s5ri4qs.5at\input\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.kproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
 2>Done Building Project "D:\temp\3s5ri4qs.5at\input\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.kproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
 1>Done Building Project "D:\temp\3s5ri4qs.5at\input\WebApplication1.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

   "D:\temp\3s5ri4qs.5at\input\WebApplication1.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "D:\temp\3s5ri4qs.5at\input\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.kproj" (default target) (2) ->
     D:\temp\3s5ri4qs.5at\input\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.kproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.03
```

I've already followed [this solution](http://druss.info/2013/10/deploy-mvc-4-application-wcf-service-to-the-free-appharbor-cloud/) to a similar issue. But it doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: Please check all references in your project, and make sure that it is in project only. see.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636406/appharbor-thirdy-party-dll-and-gac-referenced-dll

Comment: Does AppHarbor.com support MVC 6 yet? I don't see anything on their website.

Comment: I have the same question - is the MVC6 is supported?